# ffmpeg - extract every frame from a video, no quality loss, and resize shorter side to 256

Tags: ffmpeg

This line of code extracts every frame.

```
ffmpeg -i "%1" frames/out-%03d.jpg
```

How do I resize the video such that the SHORTER SIDE is 256px then extract every frame? I also do not want to have any lossy compression or whatever term it is called. I know that resizing an image will lead to some loss in quality but that is all. I do not want the frames to be saved at a lower quality.

Comment: Reducing the size == loss of quality. There is absolutely no escaping that. The more the reduction, the greater the loss. 256 pix from 1080p input would be about 1/4 quality even if no other considerations were taken into account.

Comment: Got it. Do the different file formats have different compressions? Like png is better than jpg. I don't know I dont study these things I just read them online. I guess I should have just mentioned that I would like them resized and converted to frames and not mention anything about loss of quality.

Comment: png is lossless, jpg is lossy. jpg at 100% is almost lossless but is pretty much the same file size as png.

Comment: See [How to set short side of video to a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630325/)

Answer (score 0):

What you most probably want to do is the following:

```
ffmpeg -i "%1" -vf "scale='if(gt(a,1),-2,256)':'if(gt(a,1),256,-2)'" -qscale:v 2 frames/out-%03d.jpg
```

Basically, this applies a filter on the input video which will scale down the video depending on the aspect ratio (`a`). So for landscape videos it will set the height to 256px and for portrait videos it will set the width to 256px.

If you do not want to apply any (further) lossless compression at all, you probably want to go with .png file format for the images, but if you use .jpg with a high enough quality (defined by `-qscale:v`) you will most likely not see any difference at all but might achive a slightly smaller file size.